# Operaciones de fecha en Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macros

me solicitaron a realizar un macro en VBA y se me está presentando un problema de que tengo que realizar una operación con fechas, recupero la fecha en el formato **"hh,mm"** [15:59] y al intentar hacer una sustracción entre dos fechas me genera un error 13, de que no coinciden los tipos.
Alguna sugerencia que me recomienden, la verdad nunca he echo macros. 
De ante mano muchas gracias.

```
h2 = Format(Range(strColumnaC).Value, "hh:mm")
h1 = Format(Range(strColumnaC).Value, "hh:mm")
h3 = h2-h1
```

Comment: has probado con [`DateDiff()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php)?

Comment: No lo habia checado, como decía es mi primer macro pero ya lo revicé y sí funciona.    `h1 = Range(strColumnaC).Value` , `h2 = Range(strColumnaC).Value` y finalmente la operacion es así `h3 = DateDiff("n", h1, h2)`

Comment: Me alegra que funcionara. Pues entonces puedes publicar una respuesta explicando como hacerlo funcionar para que futuros users tengan una respuesta  :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He solucionado el problema con la ayuda de los comentarios.

```
h1 = Range(strColumnaC).Value
h2 = Range(strColumnaC).Value
```

Y finalmente calculo el resultado de está manera, **"n"** inidica que el resultado que quiero es en formato minutos.

```
h3 = DateDiff("n", h1, h2)
```